# Group_by ID, the keep row with attribute R

Tags: r, summarize, across

Table:

```
ID <- c("01", "01", "02", "02) 
Accept_Medicare <- c("Opt-out", "Accept", "Opt-Out", "Accept")
Data <- c("yes", "no", "no", "no")
```

I have a dataset with multiple of the same ID, and a column "Accept_Medicare." I want to deduplicate the data set to only have one ID per row. Within each ID, I want to select the row that has the value "Opt-Out" in the "Accept_Medicare" column. Each ID only has one row where Accept_Medicare can be "Opt-Out". Here's what I've tried but it's not picking the "Opt-Out" rows.

```
combo1 <- combo1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(Status = any(`Accept_Medicare` == "Opt-Out"), across(everything(), 
~first(.x))
```

I would like the result to be two rows with this data.

```
01 | "Opt-out" | "yes"
02 | "Opt-out" | "yes"
```

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: There's a missing quotation mark in the code that defines `ID` and the code to generate the data frame `combo1` is missing. Apart from that: I think you need to try dplyr `group_by` and `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

we are looking for `group_by` followed by `filter(Accept_Medicare == "Opt-Out")`

```
library(dplyr)

combo1 <- combo1 %>%
          group_by(ID) %>%
          filter(Accept_Medicare == "Opt-Out")
```